# opencv copyMakeBorder exception at memory

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, padding

I'm working with opencv for adding border in my image but I get an runtime error: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017F1DC

Here is the my code:

```
 cv::Mat img2(img.rows + (nr - M),img.cols + (nc-N),img.depth());

 int top = (int)ceil((nr - M) / 2);
 int bottom = (int)floor((nr - M) / 2);
 int left = (int)ceil((nc - N) / 2);
 int right = (int)floor((nc - N) / 2);

 try
 {
     cv::copyMakeBorder(img, img2, top, bottom, left, right, BORDER_REFLECT);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     cout << "error message :" << e.msg;
 }
```

I hope you are help me.

Best regards.

Comment: make sure that you're not using debug OpenCV libs in release, or viceversa. Also, you don't need to initialize `img2`. Be sure that the borders are `>= 0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Miki. Problem was borders and when I absoluted border values, problem was solved.